# Try Face Id Again button does nothing in iOS Simulator

Tags: react-native

I am working on integrating **react-native-fingerprint-scanner**(https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner) package.

I am testing my app on **iOS Simulator**. I don't have an iOS real device.

So when I click on **Non-matching Face** like below[image]
It prompts me below image alert[image]

but when tapping on **Try Face ID Again** It does nothing and also nothing shows in debug console. so what are the actual causes of this behavior? would this only occurs on a simulator or also occurs on an iOS real device.

```
import FingerprintScanner from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';

  const handleBiometricAuth = async () => {
    const isSensorAvailable = await FingerprintScanner.isSensorAvailable();

    const DESCRIPTION = `Scan your ${
      isSensorAvailable === 'Face ID' ? 'face' : 'fingerprint'
    } on the device scanner to continue`;
    try {
      const result = await FingerprintScanner.authenticate({
        description: DESCRIPTION,
      });
      console.log('result ==>>>', result);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error?.message);
    }
  };
```

**My Working Environment**

```
Platform: iOS
"react-native": "0.64.1",
"react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^6.0.0",
"simulator": "iPhone 11 Pro Max"
also tried on "iPhone 12"
```

Comment: it seems like a simulator thing

Answer (score 0):

Before pressing the button again, try to change the Face id to the Matching face status.

Comment: Yes after clicking on Matching face status it's working and it's successfully thrown success message.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems to be a simulator issue. Did you try with a real device? Check this thread -> https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-touch-id/issues/212#issuecomment-514211940